# Convert all properties value of a specific object type with Math.Round?

Tags: c#

I've a specific object type with this structure:

```
public class PoissonFullTime
{
    public double HomeWin { get; set; } //1
    public double Draw { get; set; }  //X
    public double AwayWin { get; set; } //2
    public double HomeWinDraw { get; set; } //1X
```

now calling a specific method I get the properties valorized like this:

[image]

this values are stored inside this object:

```
var fullTimeForecast = poisson.GetFullTimeForecast();
```

is possible iterate to each properties of `fullTimeForecast` and convert the value into `Math.Round(value, 2)`? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say modify `GetFullTimeForecast` which presumably sets those values, make it also do the rounding.

Comment: It is possible to do that in the property getter/setter as suggested by the answers, but I would advice against it if those values will be involved in more calculations before the end result is reached, since rounding can accumulate to significant errors .. I think it is best to do the rounding right before you present the final data, in whichever form that is, using something like HomeWin.ToString("#0.00")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reflection** will help to solve your problem, it will update all objects's properties with type `double` using `Math.Round` ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RY5Fmo)):

```
var fullTimeForecast = new PoissonFullTime { AwayWin = 123.3123123 };
fullTimeForecast.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(double)).ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.SetValue(
            fullTimeForecast, 
            Math.Round((double)x.GetValue(fullTimeForecast), 2)
        )
    );
```

Comment: this will return an error: implicit cast from void to PoissonFullTime

Comment: What is value of `fullTimeForecast` at your case?

Comment: The values are the properties in the image that I've attached to my question.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not working? Try this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RY5Fmo).

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own getters/setters instead of auto-implementation.

```
private double _homeWin;
public double HomeWin { 
    get { return _homeWin; } 
    set { this._homeWin = Math.Round(value, 2); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use properties:

```
private double a;
public double A {
    get { return Math.Round( a, 2); }
    set { a = value; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you do the rounding in the getter.

Comment: @Maarten I thought about that too, but perhaps you'd want 2 public properties referencing the same private variable, one with 2 points of precision and the other with double precision. My answer discards excess data assuming a constant precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in your class the properties to have exact value, to calculate exact percentages, but you want to show them to the user with double percentage, you can do this using reflection.

```
        PoissonFullTime obj = new PoissonFullTime();
        var propertyInfos = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach(var prop in propertyInfos)
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, Math.Round((double)prop.GetValue(obj), 2));
        }
```

Be aware reflection has performance cost. Another approach is to have second properties called `AlwaysWinRound`. This will lead to duplicating your properties and you should change implementation of your previous ones.

```
private double _alwaysWin;

public double AlwaysWin
{
    get { return _alwaysWin; }
    set { _alwaysWin = value; }
}
public double AlwaysWinRound
{
    get { return Math.Round(_alwaysWinRound, 2); }
}
```